# Is it proper to say “她给我帮助”？

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice, vocabulary

What are the ways of saying somebody helped you in Chinese?

For example, I want to say, "My Chinese friend gave me some help for writing my Chinese essay."

Is this correct?: "我的中国朋友给我帮助写我的中文文章”。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since 帮助 itself can be a verb for 'help', you can simply write:

[1. 我的中国朋友][2. 帮助][3. 我][ 4.写(omit *我的*)中文文章]

[1. subject][2. verb][3. object][4. relative clause ]

> If you use 帮助 as a noun for 'assistance' then the structure would be:

[1. 我的中国朋友][2. 给][3. 我][4. 写中文文章的][5. 帮助]

[1. subject] [2. verb] [3. indirect object][4. adjectival clause for the direct object][5. direct object]

> The problem with 我的中国朋友给我帮助写我的中文文章 is the placement of the adjectival clause for the direct object.

[1. 我的中国朋友][2. 给][3. 我][4. 帮助][5. 写我的中文文章]

[1.subject][2.verb][3.indirect object][4.direct object] [5.adjectival clause for the direct object]

> It should be placed before the direct object with the possessive particle [**的**]

[1. 我的中国朋友][2. 给][3. 我][5. 写(omit *我的*)中文文章][**的**][4. 帮助]

Comment: Wow thank you so much for that super helpful explanation!! :))))

Answer (score 1):

It's probably grammatically correct, but a native speaker would just say 她帮我。

Comment: for confirmation check １００'s of sample sentences for "help,give help,give help with, 帮助＂ at jukuu